# Fancybox loads, but doesn't contain any images, even though i'm pretty sure the images are in the correct place

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I'm having a problem using jQuery Fancybox. it works beautifully locally, but not when it is uploaded to the server. Fancybox itself seems to be working, as when i click an image, it brings up the box, but it does not contain any images. I've checked all of the file locations, and from what i can tell, everything looks to be correct, however i am the furthest thing from a programmer. The page in question is located at:

http://www.houseimprovement.us/project.html

The images used there for the time being are stock photos that I intend to replace once i get everything working.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
<img alt="" id="fancy_img" src="../../AGD/scripts/jquery.fancybox/http://www.houseimprovement.us/photos/project1_full.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Even so you are "pretty" sure the path isn't right.

Instead of

```
<img alt="" id="fancy_img" src="../../AGD/scripts/jquery.fancybox/http://www.houseimprovement.us/photos/project1_full.png">
```

it should be:

```
<img alt="" id="fancy_img" src="http://www.houseimprovement.us/photos/project1_full.png">
```